# Obtaining the frequency value after using 'findpeaks' in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to find the amplitude and frequency of peaks of FFT of an audio signal.
After performing FFT Ive used the following code;

```
peak_points = [];

    fmin = 60;
    fmax = 1000;
    region_of_interest = fmax>f & f>fmin;
    froi = f(region_of_interest);

    [p_max,loc] = max(seg_fft2(region_of_interest))

    % index into froi to find the frequency of the peaks
    p_max;
    f_p_max = froi(loc);

    [points, locatn] = findpeaks(seg_fft2(region_of_interest));

    aboveMax = points > 0.4*p_max;
    if any(aboveMax)
        peak_points = [peak_points ; points(aboveMax) locatn(aboveMax)];
    end
```

Though Im able to get the correct amplitudes, `locatn(aboveMax)` doesn't give me the frequency.....
What do I need to do to get the frequency value? I tried the following line instead of `locatn(aboveMax)` which is `froi(locatn(aboveMax))` but I get the error

> ??? Error using ==> horzcat
>
> CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `locatn` is a vector of indices, so you need to use them to index in your frequency vector, e.g. `froi(locatn)` if `froi` is your vector of frequencies should give you the frequencies of the peaks

Comment: Ok so how can i write a code so I can get the peak amplitudes as well as the frequency values after each loop??

Comment: Like I said, `points` are the peak amplitudes, `locatn` the indices of the corresponding frequencies in your frequency vector.